# ess - how to make file templates (boiler plate texts)

Tags: r, ess, yasnippet

I've been using [`r-autoyas`](https://github.com/mattfidler/r-autoyas.el) 'as-is' from what I got after installation. How do I customize it or install any other plugins that let me have templates for R documents (i.e. .R, .Rmd) whenever I create a new file?

For example, I want to put some boiler plate text:

```
Copyright info

Author

Date 

File sections
```

The 'File sections' are different sections marker texts. For example:

```
## Library Import
## Functions
## Main Code
```

Maybe these can all be done with yas-snippets, but I don't know how to create custom snippet yet.